# What is the pronunciation for the word 'pluriharmonic'?

Tags: pronunciation

Maybe this problem is a bit too trivial for some people. I could not find any dictionary giving me a pronunciaiton for the word 'pluriharmonic'. Google does not work, either.
Will someone be kind enough to give me a pronunciation for this word? It is a word from mathematics. I guess since it is a compound word, 'pluri-harmonic' may be its correct form.
So will someone give me some information on the 'pluri' part? How is it pronounced?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I suppose mathematicians chose 'pluriharmonic' to clearly differentiate their usage from 'multiharmonic', which would be used in all other contexts, though I'm not sure why that should have been necessary. But given they effectively "invented" the term, and *they* don't hyphenate it, I think you can safely assume the "correct" form is unhyphenated. They do write *complex-valued pluriharmonic*, and *para-pluriharmonic*, so it's not like mathematicians avoid using hyphens in general.

Answer (score 5):

The entire word may not be in online dictionaries, but its parts certainly are. [OxfordDictionaries.com](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pluri-?q=pluri-) has:

> **pluri-** /ˈplʊəri/, *combining form*: several
>
> **harmonic** /hɑːˈmɒnɪk/, *adjective*: relating to a harmonic progression

So: /ˈplʊəri/ /hɑːˈmɒnɪk/, or in simplified form: **plu**-ri-hahr-**mon**-ik

As a [classical compound](http://www.enotes.com/topic/Classical_compound), it's not necessarily hyphenated, but looking at other words compounded from *pluri-* (*pluripotent*, *plurilateral*, etc.), it appears that it is not:

> **pluriharmonic**

Comment: That /plʊərɪ/ pronunciation makes no sense to me. That should be two syllables, not three. The Brits invent strange notations.  See John Lawler’s answer for much more sensible renderings.

Comment: @tchrist: It's a diphthong. More strictly speaking, it can be transcribed as /ʊə̯/ to show that the schwa is non-syllabic, but that is not necessary; you can compare it to transcriptions like /eɪ/, /aɪ/ and /aʊ/. It's a standard British notation (even though the pronunciation it notates is somewhat archaic); the fact that it is not American does not make it "strange." This site is not restricted to any one form of English.

Answer (score 3):

OED doesn't have this, but it does have others to model your pronunciaiton on.  For example pluriflorous

> Brit.   /ˌplʊərɪˈflɒrəs/ , /ˌplɔːrɪˈflɒrəs/ , U.S. /ˌplʊrəˈflɔrəs/

pluriparity

> Brit.   /ˌplʊərɪˈparᵻti/ , /ˌplɔːrɪˈparᵻti/ , U.S. /ˌplʊrəˈpɛrədi/

Comment: I have no idea what /plʊərɪ/ would be.  That makes no sense to me to have two vowels before the *r*, and I do not think anyone actually says it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the prefix is /'plərə/, or /'plʊrə/ in careful speech; almost certainly it wouldn't end in /i/ in a compound.

The initial /h/ in *harmonic* may or may not be pronounced, since it's stressed on the second syllable like *historic*, and prefixation wouldn't shift its stress.

So, all together then, if it were a frequently pronounced word, it would be /'plərəhar'manək/, with two stresses, one of which might be slightly louder than the other -- but which one would vary.

But it's obviously made up from classical roots, so anybody might well pronounce it any way at all, since it's not a common word to most readers.

Comment: ... and I would use the /i/ ... same sound as in, for example, *multidimensional* and *sesquicentennial*

Comment: ... both of which I'd pronounce with a shwa. Takes all kinds...

Comment: @John: You'd pronounce the first "i" in *multidimensional* as a schwa? I've always thought my own speech was about as degenerate as it gets (my standard set of phonemes is unusually small, and I reduce a *lot* of vowels to schwas). But even I would make the effort to articulate that first "i", *and* the "h". Truly, as you say, it takes all kinds.

Comment: It's not a question of _"degeneracy"_, it's a question of /fæspichrulz/. Unstressed vowels get centralized more and more the faster people speak. This is a fact about English that may be ignored by native speakers, and normally is, but it's crucial knowledge for non-natives trying to understand speech.

Answer (score 1):

Pronounce 'pluri' so that it rhymes with 'furry'.

PLUR-i-har-MON-ic.

Comment: I would accent the MON, not the Har and Ic.

Comment: The word is har-MON-ic, not HAR-mo-ny.

Comment: I have to take some time to understand how to pronounce 'pluri'to rhyme with 'furry'.Thank you very much.

Comment: A natural way to look it would be to stress the syllable immediate following the prefix.

Comment: D'oh! Yes. Edited.

Comment: "Pluri" doesn't rhyme with "furry" in all accents.