# "Multi-" prefix pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I often hear native English speakers pronouncing "multi-" as ['mʌltaɪ] (mul-tie), however all the dictionaries are saying that the only way to pronounce it is ['mʌltɪ] (mul-ty). Example words: multitasking, multimedia.

What is the right or more often used pronunciation? Does it differ in British/American English? Does it depend on context?

Comment: Isn’t this a general reference question?

Comment: I am reminded of this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52604/

Comment: I appreciate all the answer. But as per the pronunciation I need to know that is this pronunciation of a **particular zone** in America or it is **common term use in US- English**.

Comment: This is not a pronunciation (like *nukular, warsh,* or *keeng*) which is common in one region of the U.S., but which might be ridiculed if you use it in another region.

Comment: That means it is common word and It is frequently used in US - english. So we can use it in our regular communication.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The prefix comes from a plural form of the Latin quantifier *multus* 'many'. As with other Latin plurals ending in *-ī,* the English pronunciations vary.

The Latin /ī/ was pronounced in Middle English as long /i:/ (as in Modern English *seen*), but the [Great Vowel Shift (GVS)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/GreatVowelShift.pdf), which turned Middle into Modern English, moved all the ME long vowels up a step on the vowel chart.

That meant that words like *mice* and *house* (/mi:s/ and /hu:s/ in ME), which were already at the top of the chart, couldn't go any further. So, to make room for ME /e:/ and /o:/ (as in *seen* and *soon*) at the top, they fell off and became diphthongs. In particular, ME high front /i:/ became ModE /ai/ , while ME high back /u:/ became ModE /au/.

Which is why *mice* and *house* are now pronounced /mais/ and /haus/.  This means that *multi-* can be pronounced as in Latin or Middle English as /ˈməlti-/, **or** in post-GVS fashion as /ˈməltai-/.

Comment: Rather than coming from the Latin plural form *multī,* it seems that *multi-* came from the Latin combining form *multĭ-.* The OED says " < classical Latin *multi-,* combining form ... of *multus* much, many". I think the use of /aɪ/ is from analogy with the traditional English pronunciation of Latin words ending in *-i* like *alumni* etc., but it isn't exactly the same phenomenon.

Comment: I wonder, if one bases one's pronunciation of *multi* on the Latin root, should the *u* not e pronounced as such, i.e. not "malti" but, so to write, "moolti", i.e. "mooltee* (but with short vowels)?

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann Professor Lawler has explained where the divergence in pronunciation occurred. What one ***should*** do is what 98% of other English speakers do today, not what foreign nationals over a millenium ago did. This can normally be found in dictionaries, but, where there still acceptable variants, a more specialised analysis (as requested in your new question) is valid.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this question, depends on which form of English is spoken. As a British person, I have not heard anyone British say "mul-tie". It is always "mul-tee". I have only ever heard Americans say "mul-tie". So yes, it does differ in British and American English.

Comment: Britain has a tradition of knowing and valuing classical languages. The United States of America... umph... may have other priorities. Therefore their neglicence of historical pronunciation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Oxford English Dictionary lists /ˈməltaɪ/ as a U.S. pronunciation.  When consulting "all the dictionaries", that is a good one to include.

Comment: Notice the OED also includes [a note](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/123523) about what happens when the second syllable gets reduced.

Comment: Slava said "all the dictionaries", not merely "all the free dictionaries".

Comment: OK, I admit that saying "all dictionaries" was a false generalization. What I actually meant was "all dictionaries I could easily get access to".

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct. **mul-tie** is how most Americans pronounce it. They also tend to say **an-tie** for anti- and **se-mie** for semi-.

Comment: I think I disagree, but I'm not sure what pronunciations you are indicating.  Perhaps you could show them in IPA, for less ambiguity.  See eg [bbc lessons](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/pron/sounds/) for guides to IPA sounds and notations.